# Dynamically scroll when page have overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue with the scrolling for a while and I can't find an answer for it.

So, my page has `overflow: hidden` and I cannot change this. I want to make the page scroll to an element but  I have been unsuccessful with that, I mean, `scrollIntoView` can scroll but it doesn't work as I intend it to so I'm trying to implement my own scrolling function.

I have tried `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` and they won't work on my page due to the `overflow: hidden`, also since this is an angular project we don't want to import the jQuery library.

Anyone faced a similar issue before or have any idea how I can overcome this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share minimal coding example.

Comment: What code can I actually share if I described already everything? CSS -> overflow: hidden, TypeScript -> Non-working: window.scrollTo and window.scrollBy

Comment: share code it will be helpful us.